# how to access a field through custom get and set methods in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

I am writing a hibernate application. And I am using XML mappings (no annotations any where in app). HOw can I use custom methods in place of field name in xml file?
Similar feature is available in Eclipselink that looks like

```
<id name="uuid" type="string">
<column name="UUIDSTR" not-null="false" />
<access-methods get-method="getUUIDString" set-method="setUUIDString" />
</id>
```

How to mention same in Hibernate? I noticed there is accessor option, but no specifics about which by defaults looking for get & set methods of field. No explanation how to use some custom methods.

thanks in advance

Gopi

Answer (score 0):

I finally found answer to my own question. 
In Hibernate, attribute 'access' type is the one which gives this option of using method.

```
        <id name="UUIDString" type="string">
            <column name="UUIDSTR" not-null="true" length="50" />               
        </id>
```

the above xml mapping automatically makes hibernate to look for a method 'getUUIDString' & 'setUUIDString' instead of a field 'UUIDString' in the class. 
access="property" means access by method (no explicit mention of, property means method. may be everyone knows!!! breaking my head why two words are used with same meaning). and by default access is property. 
So, there is no way to use custom method names in hibernate. Sounds very basic. EclipseLink has this feature.

Gopi